# Angular cookies not removing cookie in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension with login/logout functionality. On login, the server returns a token which I want to store in a cookie. This happens like so :

```
function success(response) {
    if(response.data && response.data.token) {
        $cookies.putObject('depassify_auth', response.data);
        $rootScope.auth.token = $cookies.getObject('depassify_auth');
        $state.go("generate");
    }
}
```

This works fine, the cookie object is set successfully and is fine. However, upon logout, I need to remove the cookie, and that does NOT work.

```
vm.logout = function () {
    $cookies.remove('depasify_auth');
    delete $rootScope.auth.token;
    vm.goto("home");
}
```

The worst part is, with a breakpoint in the `logout` function, and manually calling the `$cookies.remove('depassify_auth')`, it still does NOT remove the cookie. Is there anything I'm missing?

I feel like the cookie is stored on a different domain than I'm trying to delete it from, but is there any way to check which domain the cookie is set on? I can't see the cookie in the devtools, nor can I find it anywhere in Chrome settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Internal pages of the extension have an URL origin of chrome-extension://id so yeah, the cookies are per-origin. You need a content script or chrome.cookies API.

Comment: Fixed it by adding {path: '/'} to both set and remove calls. Can I leave it like this, or are there any security issues this way?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by adding a default path to the `.putObject` and `.remove` calls.

```
$cookies.putObject('depassify_auth', response.data, {path: '/'});
$cookies.remove('depassify_auth', {path: '/'});
```